# Get latest Branch from list of branch hierarchy

Tags: c#, git

Im building a patch utility in c#.

I have many branches with different versions like

```
Branch_100.0.0
Branch_101.0.0
Branch_102.0.0
.
.
Etc....
```

Now moving to the point
Each branch create hierarchy like

```
Branch_100.0.0 -> Branch_100.0.1 -> Branch_100.0.2 ->  branch_100.0.N......
```

So the latest branch with number N will be containing all the changes of all privious branch and the latest ancestor branch..

So i want to get latest branch of each branch containing all the features...

Is there any command available in git that do that.

Or if not available what is the best way to do this with c# or any way...

I already have the List of branches in c# but was wondering if there is already a way in git to do that

Answer (score 2):

Should be pretty easy to achieve with [`for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) that's already sorted by refname by default:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' 'refs/tags/Branch_100.*' | tail -1
```

Replace `Branch_100.` with the prefix of your branch.

Comment: Hii @knittl as I'm making a utility for patching a commit with c#, I solved this by getting all branch list first and then group and shorting them in descending order and get last version from every branch.

Comment: Thanks for the help tho. But when i run the given command in cmd it errors into " 'tail' is not recognised as internal or external command, operable program batch file."

Comment: @Ron8320 you need an environment with `tail` installed. Git bash should include it out of the box

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using `git branch`:

```
git branch --sort=version:refname --list="Branch_*" | tail -1
```

---

For scripting purposes: add `--format="%(refname:short)"`, to be certain to not get tricked by a leading `*`  in front of the active branch:

```
git branch --sort=version:refname --format="%(refname:short)" --list="Branch_*" | tail -1
```

Comment: Uh, `version:refname` is nice! I wouldn't use `git branch` for scripting though

Comment: @knittl: you are right, the default output of `git branch` has the infamous leading `* ` in front of the active branch. I came to learn that `git branch` supports the same `--format` option as `git for-each-ref` (or `git tag` for that matter), which turns it into a `git for-each-ref` more convenient to scan branches only. Will edit my answer